# How can I convert an Android application to aab format to upload my application to Google Play

Tags: android-studio, google-play, google-developers-console, android-app-bundle

I made an app using Android Studio, but when I upload it to Google Play, it asks me for an aab file.
[image: like this image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio, select “Build => Generate Signed Bundle / APK” and follow the dialog.

[image: screenshot]

The process will leave you with a built and signed release bundle that’s ready for upload to the Play Store.

for more detailed steps go [here](https://medium.com/fasal-engineering/generate-aab-android-application-bundle-from-meteor-project-629f5d622c93).

Comment: I opened a new Android project but saved the app with this extension
com.appname.android.appname
Will this extension in this way affect the security of the application?

Comment: Technically no, but it is not advisable, and it could be used before

Answer (score 0):

In Android Stuido go to Build -> Generate signed bundle/APK and select Android application bundle.

after that, enter all your information and paths and your aab file will be generated.

for more information look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4FwkYYStF4)